# Rails 3 + Bourbon: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon/_bourbon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the bourbon gem for my CSS. It works in my development, but when I deploy to staging it breaks when I try to visit the home page:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon.
    Load path: /usr/local/www/lal-staging/releases/20140127202905
      (in /usr/local/www/lal-staging/releases/20140127202905/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)):
        2: <html>
        3:   <head>
        4:     <title>Lal</title>
        5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
        6:     
        7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        8: 
      app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:18
      app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__764987263561831936_25446520'
```

I am using capistrano to deploy, and passenger to server the app. I tried deploying a second time, and the results were the same. I also tried restarting passenger with `sudo touch tmp/restart.txt`

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'rolify'
gem 'paperclip', "~> 3.0"
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'prawn_rails'
# gem 'pdfkit'
gem "slugged", "~> 2.0.0"
gem 'ransack'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'bluecloth'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'neat'
gem 'sidekiq'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger', '1.6.1'
  gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '>= 0.11.30.pre12'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '>= 0.4.18'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'        
  gem 'factory_girl'        
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  # Deploy with Capistrano
  gem 'capistrano'
end

group :test do
  gem 'webmock'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
```

Capistrano looks like it's doing a `bundle install` successfully. So I don't know what's wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `gem 'bourbon'` inside of the assets group? Try to move it out of the assets group and try it again.

Another problem could be that capistrano is not executing `rake assets:precompile`. If you want to lazy compile your assets on staging add this to your application.rb

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test staging))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```